# More efficient SQL self join for joining 10 rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Each row in my database is JSON data. I need to join the rows based on the 'Match' field, which I believe means self joining the table. There will be exactly 10 rows with the same 'Match' field, so this means I have to join 10 times. This is incredibly inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the below query?

```
SELECT
P1.data->>'Reference_Name',
P2.data->>'Reference_Name',
P3.data->>'Reference_Name',
P4.data->>'Reference_Name',
P5.data->>'Reference_Name',
P6.data->>'Reference_Name',
P7.data->>'Reference_Name',
P8.data->>'Reference_Name',
P9.data->>'Reference_Name',
P10.data->>'Reference_Name'
from match_player_data P1
INNER JOIN match_player_data P2
on P1.data->>'Match' = P2.data->>'Match'
and P1.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P2.data->>'Reference_Name'
INNER JOIN match_player_data P3
on P1.data->>'Match' = P3.data->>'Match'
    and P1.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P2.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
INNER JOIN match_player_data P4
on P1.data->>'Match' = P4.data->>'Match'
    and P4.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P1.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P4.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P2.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P4.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
INNER JOIN match_player_data P5
on P1.data->>'Match' = P5.data->>'Match'
    and P5.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P1.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P5.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P2.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P5.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P5.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P4.data->>'Reference_Name'
INNER JOIN match_player_data P6
on P1.data->>'Match' = P6.data->>'Match'
    and P6.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P1.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P6.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P2.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P6.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P6.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P4.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P6.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P5.data->>'Reference_Name'
INNER JOIN match_player_data P7
on P1.data->>'Match' = P7.data->>'Match'
    and P7.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P1.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P7.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P2.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P7.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P7.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P4.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P7.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P5.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P7.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P6.data->>'Reference_Name'
INNER JOIN match_player_data P8
on P1.data->>'Match' = P8.data->>'Match'
    and P8.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P1.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P8.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P2.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P8.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P8.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P4.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P8.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P5.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P8.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P6.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P8.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P7.data->>'Reference_Name'
INNER JOIN match_player_data P9
on P1.data->>'Match' = P9.data->>'Match'
    and P9.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P1.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P9.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P2.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P9.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P9.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P4.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P9.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P5.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P9.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P6.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P9.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P7.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P9.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P8.data->>'Reference_Name'
INNER JOIN match_player_data P10
on P1.data->>'Match' = P10.data->>'Match'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P1.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P2.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P3.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P4.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P5.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P6.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P7.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P8.data->>'Reference_Name'
    and P10.data->>'Reference_Name' <> P9.data->>'Reference_Name'
```

Sample input:

```
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"a"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"b"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"c"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"d"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"e"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"f"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"g"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"h"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"j"}
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"k"}
{'Match':'2', 'Reference_Name":"b"}
```

Expected output:

```
{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"a"}, {'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"b"}, {'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"c"}, {'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"d"},{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"e"}, {'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"f"},{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"g"}, {'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"h"},{'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"j"}, {'Match':'1', 'Reference_Name":"k"}
{'Match':'2', 'Reference_Name":"b"}
```

Comment: Note: you can avoid the `10!` (~3M) permutations of the result set by using `>` instead of `<>`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i added smaple input and output. basically its finding the matching rows and converting them to a single row with 10 different json blobs each in their own column

Comment: @wildplasser i tried this change (and it may have improved) but the query is still very slow (so slow i haven't let it finish yet)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name btw the reason for wanting to change the format is so I can read the data into a dataframe similar to this: https://gist.github.com/jakebrinkmann/de7fd185efe9a1f459946cf72def057e

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate everything into an array:

```
select jsonb_agg(data) as matches
from match_player_data
group by data ->> 'Match'
```

If you really need each "match" as a separate column, just extract the elements from the array:

```
select matches -> 0 ->> 'Match' as match_number,
       matches -> 0 ->> 'Reference_Name' as reference_name_1,
       matches -> 1 ->> 'Reference_Name' as reference_name_2,
       matches -> 2 ->> 'Reference_Name' as reference_name_3,
       ....
from (
  select jsonb_agg(data) as matches
  from match_player_data
  group by data ->> 'Match'
) t
```

Or just collect the names, if you are not interested in the rest:

```
select match_number,
       names[1] as reference_name_1,
       names[2] as reference_name_2,
       names[3] as reference_name_3,
       ....
from (
  select data ->> 'Match' as match_number, 
         array_agg(data ->> 'Reference_Name') as names
  from match_player_data
  group by data ->> 'Match'
) t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3a05055c58340f947dbfb9270d6dd6ad)

Comment: This is what I need thanks. Is there a way to use the first query you gave and rename the elements of every field? There are a lot of fields so renaming them all manually will actually be a ton of work.

Comment: @lexxish: no, you will have to write a column alias for each column you select.

Comment: Is it possible to influence the order that the data is "grouped by"? For example I have a "Win_Status" column and I'd like the winning teams to be grouped together so you have 5 winning columns and then 5 losing columns.